# Filter Data frame using 3 different vector conditions

Tags: r

***My sample dataset***

```
df <- data.frame(period=rep(1:3,3), 
             product=c(rep('A',9)), 
             account= c(rep('1001',3),rep('1002',3),rep('1003',3)),
             findme= c(0,0,0,1,0,1,4,2,0))
```

**My Desired output dataset**

```
output <- data.frame(period=rep(1:3,2), 
                 product=c(rep('A',6)), 
                 account= c(rep('1002',3),rep('1003',3)),
                 findme= c(1,0,1,4,2,0))
```

Here my conditions are....
I want to eliminate records 3 records from 9 based on below conditions.

1. If all my periods (1, 2 and 3) meet “findme” value is equal to ‘Zero’  and

   2. if that happens to the same product  and
   3. and same account.

Rule 1: It should meet Periods 1, 2, 3 
Rule 2: Findme value for all periods = 0 
Rule 3: All those 3 records (Preiod 1,2,3) should have same Product 
Rule 4: All those 3 recods (period 1,2,3) should have one account.

Comment: Could you please clarify the rules by which you want to filter? Your question is ambiguous and not reproducible.

Comment: Rule 1: It should meet Periods 1, 2, 3 //// Rule 2: Findme value for all periods = 0 /// Rule 3: All those 3 records (Preiod 1,2,3) should have same Product /// Rule 4: All those 3 recods (period 1,2,3) should have one account.

Comment: What does that mean? Use logical operators, like `period == findme`, using words like 'meet' doesn't explain what you are thinking.

Comment: In SQL, I can write a condition that ...select * from df where period in (1,2,3) and findme = 0 and item = 'same item for period 1,2,3 and account = 'same account for period 1,2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to drop all records from a product-account combination where findme == 0, if all periods are included in this combination?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(product, account, findme) %>% 
  mutate(all.periods = all(1:3 %in% period)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!(findme == 0 & all.periods)) %>%
  select(-all.periods)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  period product account findme
   <int>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <dbl>
1      1       A    1002      1
2      2       A    1002      0
3      3       A    1002      1
4      1       A    1003      4
5      2       A    1003      2
6      3       A    1003      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[all(1:3 %in% period) & !all(!findme)], .(product, account)]$V1]
#   period product account findme
#1:      1       A    1002      1
#2:      2       A    1002      0
#3:      3       A    1002      1
#4:      1       A    1003      4
#5:      2       A    1003      2
#6:      3       A    1003      0
```